# Why isnt my mocking not working for responseEntity exchange?

Tags: spring, groovy, mockito, resttemplate

In groovy I'm trying to use the following to mock a return of a request but I keep getting a null pointer exception whenever my code calls:

```
ResponseEntity<AnimalVO> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headerUtil.headers()), AnimalVO.class);
```

In Test:

```
  when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class, any(HttpEntity.class, any(ValueObject.class) as Class)).thenReturn(responseEntityMocked)
```

I'm using mockito 3.12
My test just fails with a null pointer exception and my restTemplate exchange (upon debugging) returns a null value.
Am I doing something wrong?

If it helps the rest Temple exchange has the following definition:

```
    exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
```

Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, writing the given request entity to the request, and returns the response as ResponseEntity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), 
   any(HttpEntity.class), eq(AnimalVO.class)).thenReturn(responseEntityMocked)
```